# LISTEN / NOTIFY privileges

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a single postgres database, with two users; Alice and Bob.

I would like to be able to do a `NOTIFY alice_channel 'sensitive data'` without Bob being able to sneakily `LISTEN` in just by guessing that the channel name is 'alice_channel'.

In practice the channel names *are* very hard to guess, but this is security through obscurity at best.

Am I correct in believing that there is no way to prevent a database user from using (abusing) `LISTEN` & `NOTIFY`? *i.e.* there does not appear to be any associated privileges that can be granted or revoked.

Is this a dead end?

Comment: I don't know of a way to exclude users from listening. But if you pick a name for the channel like you would pick a secure password, wouldn't this do the job?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing at the moment (using large random strings), but it feels dirty and is rather limiting. There are some pretty cool things I could do with `LISTEN`/`NOTIFY` if I could lock it down a bit. As it stands it's a rather course-grained "poke a client to re-poll for all the data you 'might' need" feature.

Comment: I just wanted to know if things have changed since this was answered. Were you able to implement something?

Comment: If you can't trust your apps, you should not let them in. I think it is dead end in production system. There has been proposal though for related privs. https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/51CC98FB.9040700%40agliodbs.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no permissions on `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY`. It would not have made sense to have any until support for notify payloads was introduced in more recent versions.

If you want access control, create a table with the information that you want and then send a `NOTIFY` that's empty or has nothing but a primary key for that table in it. `SELECT` the row(s) of interest from the table, which *can* have access control, to get the sensitive data. This used to be the only way to use `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` to send specific data before payloads were added.

Comment: Thanks Craig I thought as much. I might take a peek at the source and see how hard it will be to implement but I'm guessing it will require a completely new database level `AclMode` and `pg_database_aclcheck` call somewhere, it's been a while since I've looked :/